# python look up list from one column and return equivalent id from different column

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help with this approach please

```
lst=['a','b','c]
```

My input data frame

```
id name score
1   a    0.2
2   b    0.3
3   c    0.4
4   d    0.5
```

My output should be of list containing values as 1,2,3

```
res=[1,2,3]
```

So dataframe should look up equivalent values in lst if it matched it should return equivalent id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then convert output `Series` to list:

```
lst=['a','b','c']
res = df.loc[df['name'].isin(lst), 'id'].tolist()
print (res)
[1, 2, 3]
```

If order of output is important and has to match values of list:

```
#for non matched values are created NaN
lst=['a','c','e','b']
res = df.set_index('name').reindex(lst)['id'].tolist()
print (res)
[1.0, 3.0, nan, 2.0]

#non matched values are removed
lst=['a','c','e','b']
res = df.set_index('name').reindex(lst)['id'].dropna().astype(int).tolist()
print (res)
[1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Thanx bro it was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

To generate your list use:

```
df.set_index('name').id.loc[lst].tolist()
```

Comment: I prefer reindex because if at least one value not matched `KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'`